# ThreadPoolExecutor has a problem when I run it, but it doesn't send any response, even though I've already written print in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

why when i run it nothing appears?

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os, sys, json, requests, hashlib

G = '\033[1;32m'
R = '\033[1;91m'
W = '\033[1;97m'
B = '\033[1;94m'

def saekomatsushita(tofu):
    N = 7
    token = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=N))
    print(tofu + ' - ' + token)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as sh:
    e = open('j.txt').read()
    _ = [sh.submit(saekomatsushita, e)]
```

Please help, I'm very tired because of this one problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't import the `string` and `random` modules. This will cause an error and your subthread will terminate. You don't see any error message because `ThreadPoolExecutor` threads will not print any `exception` message when any exception occur. Because your `saekomatsushita()` function will be executed (in source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor`) like below ;

```
try:
    saekomatsushita()

except BaseException as exc:
    # something
```

To solve this, you can use `try except` block in your subthread (in `saekomatsushita` func), or you can call `result()` method of future object.

Here is the description of result(timeout=None) method in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result):

**result**(timeout=None) :

> Return the value returned by the call. If the call hasn’t yet
> completed then this method will wait up to timeout seconds. If the
> call hasn’t completed in timeout seconds, then a
> concurrent.futures.TimeoutError will be raised. timeout can be an int
> or float. If timeout is not specified or None, there is no limit to
> the wait time.
>
> If the future is cancelled before completing then CancelledError will be raised.
>
> If the call raised an exception, this method will raise the same exception.

Here is the first solution ;

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os, sys, json, requests, hashlib

G = '\033[1;32m'
R = '\033[1;91m'
W = '\033[1;97m'
B = '\033[1;94m'

def saekomatsushita(tofu):
    try:
        N = 7
        token = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=N))
        print(tofu + ' - ' + token)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error: {}".format(e))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as sh:
    e = open('j.txt').read()
    _ = [sh.submit(saekomatsushita, e)]
```

Here is the second solution :

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os, sys, json, requests, hashlib

G = '\033[1;32m'
R = '\033[1;91m'
W = '\033[1;97m'
B = '\033[1;94m'
def saekomatsushita(tofu):
    N = 7
    token = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=N))
    print(tofu + ' - ' + token)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as sh:
    e = open('j.txt').read()

    future = sh.submit(saekomatsushita, e)
    future.result()
```